# libGDX 1.0 installation error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I just download last nightly version from libGDX.
When execute gdx-setup.jar configure some items, generate the project and after download some packages i received this message:

```
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-box2d-platform/1.0.0/gdx-box2d-platform-1.0.0-natives-x86.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-backend-android/1.0.0/gdx-backend-android-1.0.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx/1.0.0/gdx-1.0.0.pom

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         eclipseworkspace:android:1.0
         eclipseworkspace:android:1.0 > eclipseworkspace:core:1.0
      > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-box2d/1.0.0/gdx-box2d-1.0.0.pom'.
         > The target server failed to respond

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8 mins 59.357 secs
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Gradle Project
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Import -> build.gradle
To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...
```

How can i fix that?

PS: On my Eclipse (Indigo version) i can not find the option File -> Import -> Gradle -> Gradle project

Comment: Are you behind a firewall of some kind that might block maven? Have you tried running with the --stacktrace option?

Comment: @KevinWorkman i just upgrade from  Eclipse indigo to Kepler and following step by step the libGDX installation guide now works fine with out errors.